# I can't get IntelliJ to recognise my Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, intellij-idea

I am trying to make Android programs using IntelliJ.  Unfortunately, I cannot get the Android SDK to be recognised on IntelliJ.  (I.e. Eclipse has Android SDK Manager installed just fine.)

I select create new project from scratch.
I give the project a name and select make Android module.
Create source directory (next).

The computer then shows Android SDK none.  I click the ellipses (...) and the program can see my JDK files.

I click on the + and select Android SDK.

I then find the directory c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk.

However, when I click OK a dialog box appears stating "Please select Java SDK".  It only gives me the choice of 1.6 (and not the other one 1.7).  I then press OK for 1.6.

Finally the computer then reports it cannot find any Android targets in this SDK.

Please help!!!!

Comment: I'm still having trouble on IntelliJ 12 Community Edition on OSX 10.8.2. It refuses to accept my SDK. It never adds it no matter what I do, and the select box always only reads ````<No Project SDK>```` in the label in red. No errors, just nothing happening. The docs are outdated, and this version just isn't doing what I want it to.

Answer (score 49):

Before creating a new Android Project on IntelliJ Idea, you need to configure the Java and Android Development Kits at the IDE level.

Assuming you already installed the JDK and the Android SDK and you just launched IntelliJ (I'm using version 13.0.2):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (to access the Project Structure dialog)
2. On the left navigation pane, click on 'Project Settings->Project'
3. On the right navigation pane, you should see a drop-down list displaying '<No SDK>'
4. Click on 'New', select 'JDK' and choose the path to your JDK
5. Click on 'New', select 'Android SDK' and choose the path to your Android SDK

Please note you have to define the JDK before the Android SDK.

This procedure is documented at:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html

Comment: i do this on ubuntu add jdk added! but sdk still not appear! what should i do?

Comment: If you've just installed Android SDK then there may not be any "platforms" installed yet. So you need to run Android SDK Manager and install at least one platform. (And in my case I had to run Android SDK Manager as Administrator to get it to work.)

Answer (score 27):

On linux, run tools/android under the SDK to run the Android SDK Manager.  Then download one or more of the platforms.  Check out "SDK Readme.txt" in the SDK directory for more.  Once you're done there, you will be able to select a platform, and your IntelliJ system will start to run.

Answer (score 21):

For others who may encounter this issue on Intellij14 + Mac - the solution that worked for me was to

1) Open intellij - select add android sdk from the project settings section, select the android-sdk-macrox root directory

2) the sdk manager pops up - download at least 1 package.

3) Restart intellij (without this restart, it didnt seem to work)

Comment: Where i can find the option to open SDK mananger from intellij? I tried everything and i cant make this work. (also on mac with intellij14)

Comment: I changed the answer to explain how i got the sdk manager to pop up

Comment: Restarting was the clincher!

Comment: Yeah. this is the answer of the question. in alternatively you can make an symbolic link then intellij points it. `ln -s $ANDROID_HOME android_sdk`, then in file explorer you can see `android_sdk`

Answer (score 6):

Oddly, IntelliJ 12 Community doesn't give us the option to select the JDK location for Android projects.
I've found a workaround for this:

1. First, create a new **Java** project. I used 'Java Hello World' project. This'll give you the chance to select your JDK.
2. Install the Android SDK and run the Android SDK Manager to install tools and a platform, as others have mentioned.
3. Create a new Android project. Under 'SDK', select the Android SDK. Intellij will remember the JDK location you defined in step #1.

Answer (score 4):

On Mac, IntelliJ won't detect the installation of Android SDK. When selecting SDK for new Android module, select your `android-sdk-macosx` folder as your location.
More info: https://peterboctor.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/installing-the-android-sdk-on-mac-os-x/

Alternatively, Google just releases Android Studio which is a whole IDE base on IntelliJ.

Comment: That link and the instructions it points to worked for me -- the only change i made was to add my android sdk tools directory to my PATH. Note that I also had to restart my IDE.

Answer (score 3):

With IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2, I couldn't select the Android SDK install location on Mac OS X.  That install location was ~/Library/Android/sdk, which IntelliJ wouldn't navigate to because ~/Library is a hidden folder.  So I created a symlink in my home directory (ln -s ~/Library/Android/sdk/ ~/AndroidSDK) and IntelliJ DID let me select that.

Comment: Exactly and you need to add "~/AndroidSDK" to the paths file.

Comment: I was able to select /usr/local/opt/android-sdk by just typing it, the slash at the beginning opens a text entry box.

Comment: @js. nice trick for prompting the search with the `/`. Didn't know that. However, I still wasn't able to navigate to `~/Library/Android`. So +1 for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

(linux, osx)

When going standalone (without Android Studio), make sure you have the sdk **tools** (from the standalone sdk, "command line tools" option), **build-tools**, **platform-tools** and an sdk (**platform**).

```
./tools/bin/sdkmanager --update

# list available packages (pick a version)
./tools/bin/sdkmanager --list

# install requeriments
./tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;26.0.0"
./tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-26"

# you might get wrong permissions from the downloaded packages
sudo chmod -R +rxw tools # will need write perm to create AVDs
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This is what worked for me for existing IDE

Comment: Yep, also worked for me. I downloaded the 'android-sdk' via Homebrew/Cask and then used the sdkmanager to install build-tools, platform-tools, and platform (tools are already provided) Once all four packages are present, IntelliJ recognizes it as a valid SDK!

Answer (score 1):

This may help others. I found that I couldn't get IntelliJ (MacOS) to recognise the Android targets in the android-sdk-macosx folder. Moving the Android SDK folder out of the Applications folder and into a directory in my User's folder resolved the issue. IntelliJ was then able to recognise the Android SDK. It may have had something to do with permissions, but no errors were shown to indicate this. Hope this helps.

Comment: same issues on linux, having the SDK in /opt. creating a symlink from /home/user/sdk -> /opt/sdk makes it work... Oo

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with version 15 intelliJ  after upgrading  on OS Linux Ubuntu 12.04

I found because the android sdk wasn't in the home folder of the user running intelliJ  that you had to change the Folder/file permissions before it would see this

Mine was in the root

Issuing the command `chown -R <yourusername> /path/to/android_sdk_dir` 
solved the problem for me

If this fails after doing this delete the `~/.ideaC(Lastversion number)` any previous `~/.ideaC(Lastversion numbers)`  folder's and then re open intelliJ

You will have to go through the initialization of the IDE and give the path to your Java installation ver8 upwards only on intelliJ version15  and thereafter  your android sdk installation

I found this can also cause conflicts

As a further tip add the following to the very end of  your `~/.bashrc`  using one of your editors my (nano , vi etc )

Example `vi ~/.bashrc`

The following lines set the Android Path

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/android/:/path/to/android/tools
export PATH
```

For SDK version r_08 and higher, also add these two lines for adb:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/android/platform-tools
export PATH
```

for setting android emulator to 32 bit version add this line

```
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
```

Exit your choice of editor (vi , nano etc )  and 
Re invoke bashrc with the command below

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Hope that helps you

Comment: Greetings and welcome to StackOverflow, I see you have a lot of code/snippet sections to your answer here and you may want to edit those as code blocks to make them pop more from the standard message text. To help you out heres the [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) page in the help center.

Comment: FYI: this code can also be placed in your `~/.bash_profile` which is where I like to put my terminal init stuff.

Comment: @BrandonBuck, i edited for code formatting. Changes will appear if it passes peer review. Thanks for helping the community.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `SDK Manager.exe` to download at least one of the platforms, then you'll be able to select the downloaded platform, [see also this tutorial](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Simple_Android_application_from_scratch_in_IntelliJ_IDEA_10.5).

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy server :

1.After starting the Android-SDK-Manager, go to :
Tools > Options.

Add your proxy details.

2.Then go to Packages > Reload

3.After this you should be able to see all the platform options of the Android.

PS : Pheew! Spent an hour figuring this out!

Answer (score 0):

You can create symlink to your sdk location, even to hidden folder. And then point point IDEA to symlink.
For example: `ln -s /Users/*username*/Library/Android/sdk /Users/*username*/androidsdk`

Comment: For the GUI-oriented Mac user, you can accomplish the same task in Finder. Navigate to android folder, select the `sdk` folder, right-click on it and select `Make Alias`. Then drag that folder to the non-hidden directory of your choice. In `IntelliJ > Project Structure`, select `+ then Android SDK`. You can now choose the alias to add the sdk to your project.