# IntelliJ 12.1.4 with Android Platform 4.2.2 on OSX compile error: Android SDK is parsed incorrectly

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have spent some time doing iOS development, but I am new to Android development. I use IntelliJ as my go to IDE for Java projects and really wanted to use it for my dive into Android development. Steps so far:

- Installed Android SDK and downloaded the 4.2.2 platform and tools.
- Created new project in IntelliJ selecting the Android Application module type.
- Pointed the module settings to use the 4.2.2 Android SDK and Java 1.6.
- Attempted to run the default run configuration built by IntelliJ.

I get the following compile error:

```
Information: Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 1 sec
Information: 2 errors
Information: 0 warnings
Error: Android Source Generator: Android SDK is parsed incorrectly. Parsing log:
Error parsing the sdk.
Error: Android Source Generator: [untitled2] Android SDK is invalid or not specified
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not run into this yet, but in the Module Settings dialog I would check the following:

- Project: Project SDK
- Modules: for all modules: Module SDK. It's usually set to "Project SDK".

I also set the environment variable ANDROID_HOME.

If it still fails, I'd like to point you to [I can't get IntelliJ to recognise my Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627689/i-cant-get-intellij-to-recognise-my-android-sdk?rq=1).

Comment: I verified the Project SDK and Module SDK pointed to my Android SDK.  I set ANDROID_HOME. I added Android tools to my PATH.  Still the same error from IntelliJ.  So, I downloaded Android Studio which is based on IntelliJ, and I'm using that for now.  Thanks for the suggestions.